# Is it possible to create a touch application to interact with another application, "sharing" focus betwen the two?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, windows-8, touch

What I am trying to do is have a helper application that a user can use touch input to affect a second application. I have been able to send keystrokes to the second application, but the problem I am having is when I want to hold a button down.

For example on my application, I want to be able to hold down a button which would simulate a ctrl key down. And while this button is touched, I want to be able to interact with the second application. And if the user lets go of the button, then the ctrl key is undressed. I can kind of get this working, except when the user does anything on the second application, the button that was held down is unpressed (because the other application gained focus).

I don't care if I have to go WPF or windows forms, just as long as I can get it working. Windows 8 or 8.1 only is acceptable as well (all clients will be 8.1).

Any help would be appreciated!

Note I added to a comment below.

*The second application is one I haven't created, it could be anything really. A scenario would be my application having a ctrl button that you could hold press and hold, for example, and in outlook click a link. Or pressing and holding a shift button in my app, while drawing with a pen in photoshop to draw a straight line. I am able to send key strokes, but just can't handle the "hold" touch command.*

Comment: Hey doobist, did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's been so long, I'm creating a new answer. I did the research, and I'm pretty sure I know what's going on. But I'm going to mention all the official resources I examined before coming to my conclusion.

### Possible packaged solutions

First off, the new [**Windows Input Simulator**](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) might fix all your troubles right out of the box. If you need the Windows API, which I'll be talking about below, check [**PInvoke.net**](http://pinvoke.net) first to see if they have documentation for the call you're trying to make.

### The Windows API way

The best place to start is the [**User Interaction**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657750(v=vs.85).aspx) article on MSDN. There's a bunch of new Winu8 Touch APIs there, but you're probably interest in the legacy [**Keyboard input**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645530(v=vs.85).aspx) article.

Every window for an application must have a [**Windows Procedure**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632593(v=vs.85).aspx) (a.k.a `WindowsProc`) that's responsible for reacting to messages it cares about (e.g. a button click, a message indicating the Window needs to draw its GUI, or the `WM_QUIT` event that alerts it to gracefully dispose of the resources held by the Window. This procedure is also responsible for handling messages from input devices, like mouse-clicks and keys on the keyboard.

In your case, you're more interested in making the Window think there's a message from the keyboard when there isn't. That's what the [**`SendInput`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) API call is for; it lets you insert an array of [**`INPUT`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646270(v=vs.85).aspx) messages, be they keyboard, mouse, or other input device directly into the queue, bypassing the need for the user to physically act. This easy API call specifically accepts [**`MOUSEINPUT`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646273(v=vs.85).aspx), [**`KEYBDINPUT`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646271(v=vs.85).aspx), or [**`HARDWAREINPUT`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646269(v=vs.85).aspx) messages.

For the keyboard, you'll get a message when a key is pressed (**`WM_KEYDOWN`**) and when it is released (**`WM_KEYUP`**), so to determine hotkeys like **`CTRL+C`**, you have to watch for **`WM_KEYDOWN`** message for the letter **`C`** that were received after a **`WM_KEYDOWN`** for the **`CTRL` key** but before its **`WM_KEYUP`** message.

#### Managing input device messages

To simulate input devices, use **`SendInput`** to pass along the **`WM_KEYDOWN`** and/or **`WM_KEYUP`** message(s) to the target Window. But don't forget that an application can have more than one window. There are API calls to get the different Windows, but it'll be up to you to write code to find it before you can use **`SendInput`** on it.a

To find out what a window believes about an input device, use [**`GetAsyncKeyState`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx). You may not be able to trust it if you've meddled with APIs related to input devices.

There is a [**`BlockInput`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646290(v=vs.85).aspx) call on a window which denies all messages except **`SendInput`** calls from the thread which blocked it. In most cases, re-enabling input as soon as possible is the right thing. The documentation say that if the blocking thread dies, **`BlockInput`** is disabled. A similar but less harsh call is [**`EnableWindow`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646291(v=vs.85).aspx) which prevents a window from receiving input focus.

The API for windows includes the ability [**to register hooks**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644960(v=vs.85).aspx), which let you [**specify kinds of messages and/or certain windows to be reviewed**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644960(v=vs.85).aspx#system_events) by a user-specified function.

Comment: Seems to have lot's of interesting articles, did you try out with the Ctrl button and see if this work? Specially on touch panels if you holding touch.

Comment: It's been a very long time and I don't remember what exactly this was for. I think we wanted to be able to remotely control a legacy application via an API. The "server" was running the legacy app and a WCF app. The WCF app listened for messages and simulates a user performing operations upon the legacy application via simulated mouse/keyboard input depending on which message it received. I don't remember if touch input was involved in my case.

Comment: FWIW, pretty sure my answer was written with WinForms (or perhaps even VB6) in mind. If I were to do something like this again and I had control over both applications, I would use WPF. Recently I created an in-app virtual touch keyboard and I was able to do everything I needed via `RoutedEvent`s. But there were other ways to manipulate input at a low level without resorting to P/Invoke and interfering with a Windows application's message loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would really like to know why you need this to be in two different applications, but here's the best I can think of.

In the applications, you should be able to subscribe to KeyDown, KeyUp, Focus, and Blur (lost focus). I'm not clear on if this is an actual button or if its touch input, but whatever the case may be, assume KeyDown is whatever event fires when the user is "simulating" the ctrl key being pressed, and KeyUp is whatever event fires when the user is ceases to "simulate" the ctrl key being down.

Set up the App1 so when it gains focus, it communicates with the App2 the state: depressed, or not depressed. Every time KeyDown or KeyUp fires, send a message to App2.

When App1's Blur event fires, stop sending messages to App2. Even though App1 will no longer have the button depressed, App2 won't know it and can continue to behave as though the button was depressed until App2 regains focus and can go back to sending messages again.

If it were me, I would have App2 have all the same logic as App1, so the moment App2 gets in Focus, it begins handling the up/down state itself. You may want to have the two applications do some kind of "handshake" when a blur/focus event happens to make sure the state is preserved when switching between. When App2 gets the Blur event, it transfers to App1 the state and they shake hands again, so App1 knows its now responsible for managing the state.

This is basically having the apps cooperate via "tag-team." They keep some state synchronized between each other, "handing off" the responsibility when the blur/focus events fire. Since you cannot know that Blur will fire on one app before Focus fires on the other, you will need to use the same mechanism that communicates the state of this "simulated button" to coordinate the apps so they never interfere with each other.

Something tells me that this doesn't completely solve your problem, but hearing *why* it doesn't will certainly get everyone closer to thinking out the rest of the way. Let me know the twist ending, eh?

Comment: I guess I could have been a bit more clear. The second application is one I haven't created, it could be anything really. A scenario would be my application having a ctrl button that you could hold press and hold, for example, and in outlook click a link. Or pressing and holding a shift button in my app, while drawing with a pen in photoshop to draw a straight line. I am able to send key strokes, but just can't handle the "hold" touch command.

Comment: @doobst If you send the keydown and keyup messages to the second app, wouldn't it always know when to perform the special action? What am I missing.

Comment: Perhaps the problem you're experiencing is that App1's is sending a keyup message before focus moves to App2. If that's the case, when you get a keyup message, wait some predefined time and then send the keyup to App2 unless a Focus event happens first. To reiterate your point, knowing that the character is down should be enough to determine if the character is being held.